# convert 2 arrays into key value object, one array hold the keys, they second is nested array of matching indexed values

Tags: javascript, arrays

combine each irritation of valueArr  it's inner member to a matching key from keysArr,
Index will always match each other.

the result I'm looking for: the key for each object and the id is equal to "internalid"
But i will work it out if it's not clear

```
const valuesArr = 
       ["10","9","Item","Bank","2","true","true","Result7","5675"],
       ["9","1","Expenses","OthExpense","4","true","true","9999","9999"],
       ["8","8","Expenses","OthAsset","6","false","false","6666","77777"],
       ["7","8","Expenses","AcctPay","4","true","true","666","7777"],
       ["6","123","123","123","123","123","123","123","123"],
       ["5","123","123","123","123","123","123","123","123"],
       ["4","Test1","Item","OthCurrAsset","2","Result5","Result6","ytrytrytryrty","32432"],
       

       ["2","Result1","Result2","Result3","Result4","Result5","Result6","Result7","Result8"],
       ["1","Test1","Test12","Test13","Test14","Test15","Test16","Test17","Test18"]]


const keysArr = 
        ["internalid",
        "custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type",
        "custrecord_st_segment_sublist",
        "custrecord_st_segment_account_type",
        "custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary",
        "custrecord_st_segment_department",
        "custrecord_st_segment_class",
        "custrecord_st_segment_location",
        "custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment"]

       
result:
       
       {"1":{"id":"1","values":{"internalid":"1","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"Test1","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Test12","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"Test13","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"Test14","custrecord_st_segment_department":"Test15","custrecord_st_segment_class":"Test16","custrecord_st_segment_location":"Test17","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"Test18"}},
       "2":{"id":"2","values":{"internalid":"2","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"Result1","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Result2","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"Result3","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"Result4","custrecord_st_segment_department":"Result5","custrecord_st_segment_class":"Result6","custrecord_st_segment_location":"Result7","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"Result8"}},
      

       "4":{"id":"4","values":{"internalid":"4","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"Test1","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Item","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"OthCurrAsset","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"2","custrecord_st_segment_department":"Result5","custrecord_st_segment_class":"Result6","custrecord_st_segment_location":"ytrytrytryrty","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"32432"}},
       "5":{"id":"5","values":{"internalid":"5","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"123","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"123","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"123","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"123","custrecord_st_segment_department":"123","custrecord_st_segment_class":"123","custrecord_st_segment_location":"123","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"123"}},
       "6":{"id":"6","values":{"internalid":"6","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"123","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"123","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"123","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"123","custrecord_st_segment_department":"123","custrecord_st_segment_class":"123","custrecord_st_segment_location":"123","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"123"}},
       "7":{"id":"7","values":{"internalid":"7","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"8","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Expenses","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"AcctPay","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"4","custrecord_st_segment_department":"true","custrecord_st_segment_class":"true","custrecord_st_segment_location":"666","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"7777"}},
       "8":{"id":"8","values":{"internalid":"8","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"8","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Expenses","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"OthAsset","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"6","custrecord_st_segment_department":"false","custrecord_st_segment_class":"false","custrecord_st_segment_location":"6666","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"77777"}},
       "9":{"id":"9","values":{"internalid":"9","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"1","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Expenses","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"OthExpense","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"4","custrecord_st_segment_department":"true","custrecord_st_segment_class":"true","custrecord_st_segment_location":"9999","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"9999"}},
       "10":{"id":"10","values":{"internalid":"10","custrecord_st_segment_transaction_type":"9","custrecord_st_segment_sublist":"Item","custrecord_st_segment_account_type":"Bank","custrecord_st_segment_subsidiary":"2","custrecord_st_segment_department":"true","custrecord_st_segment_class":"true","custrecord_st_segment_location":"Result7","custrecord_st_segment_custom_segment":"5675"}}]
```

Comment: What's your specific question about this task? Please include your code attempts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is asking how to "zip" two arrays, where one has keys and one has values.  If so, `Object.fromEntries()` [is very useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

A simple zip, goes like this:

```
// a simple zip
function zip(keys, values) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    keys.map((key, index) => [key, values[index]])
  );
}
```

The OP appears to want the lead element in the values array to be a specially named field in the new object as well as the key of the resulting object. Here, applying the simple zip...

```js
function zip(keys, values) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    keys.map((key, index) => [key, values[index]])
  );
}

// the value array contains an "id" element at the start
// produce an object that looks like { id: number, values: {...} }
function objectFromValues(keys, values) {
  return { id: values[0], values: zip(keys, values.slice(1)) }
}

const valuesArr = [
  [1, "A", "B", "C"],
  [2, "D", "E", "F"]
];
  
const keys = ["keyA", "keyB", "keyC"];

const result = valuesArr.reduce((acc, values) => {
  acc[values[0]] = objectFromValues(keys, values);
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(result)
```